# SQL*Plus Input: How do you get input from user into varchar2 variable?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I got a table with strings from `varchar2(50)` and I want to find all tuples with a name which equals to a given name.

My input part of code is

```
name:=&k;
```

(k is not declared)

but when I give a string like "Jhon" it actually uses it as value and not a string (Jhon and not 'Jhon')

so my question is how to perform a string(varchar2) input?

Comment: That is not a PL/SQL "input", it's a feature of SQL*Plus (PL/SQL can **not** interact with the user)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're running an anonymous PL/SQL block from SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer), you just need to enclose the substitution variable in quotes:

```
name := '&k';
```

For example:

```
set verify off
set serveroutput on

declare
  name varchar2(10);
begin
  name := '&k';
  dbms_output.put_line('Name is: ' || name);
end;
/

anonymous block completed
Name is: jhon
```